# Sudden error in Chrome extension: "cannot access before initialization"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, initialization

In Chrome extension to catch activated or updated tab and get an url from them i use a construction like

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) run(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});

const processingTabId = {};

function run(tab) {
    if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
    processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

    let newUrl = new URL(tab.pendingUrl || tab.url)
    currentHost = newUrl.host;
```

Some days it worked like a charm, and this extension was in use. But today, without Chrome update or any code change, i suddenly realize, that i get no url under no circumstances, not on tab activation, not on tab update (refresh). Looking into extension backend i realized an error, which was never there:

`Cannot access 'processingTabId' before initialization`

and these code lines were marked:

```
function run(tab) {
    if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
```

Do somebody know, what this error means, how it is to fix and why it happens so suddenly?

Comment: Try putting the variable declaration at the top.

Comment: This one `const processingTabId = {};` to the top? `<quietly>SEEM TO WORK!</quietly>`. Thank you! Could you briefly explain, why the error wasn't there, then rised, and then the moving of variable to the top fixed it?

Comment: One of the events that calls `run()` was getting triggered before the constant was initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `processingTabId` before you call the `run()` function that uses it. So put the declaration at the top, before adding the listeners that call `run()`.

```
const processingTabId = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) run(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});

function run(tab) {
    if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
    processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

    let newUrl = new URL(tab.pendingUrl || tab.url)
    currentHost = newUrl.host;
```